# postgresql replace function giving error while assigning it a variale in a function

Tags: postgresql, variables, replace

```
set a = replace(replace('str and ition=', ' and ', '-'), '=', '-');
```

while assigning the value of replace function it gives below error.

```
syntax error at or near "("
LINE 1: set a = replace(replace('strc and ition=', ' and ', '-'), '=...
```

it is giving error at first replace bracket.
though below query works fine.

```
select replace(replace('strc and ition=', ' and ', '-'), '=', '-');
```

Comment: don't use `set`. Write it like `a = replace(replace('str and ition=', ' and ', '-'), '=', '-');`

Comment: [Assignment](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-ASSIGNMENT)

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is `a := replace(replace('str and ition=', ' and ', '-'), '=', '-');`

Best regards,
Bjarni

Answer (score 0):

Don't Use `set` for value assignment. Write it like below:

`a = replace(replace('str and ition=', ' and ', '-'), '=', '-');`